# Android Studio 1.1.0 IDE showing false errors (in red)

Tags: android, android-studio

I have attached a screen shot to get a clear picture.

[image]

I have reinstalled Android studio but the problem is still there. The IDE compiles and runs the program. The errors are not errors otherwise the IDE would not compile and run the app. but strangely showing false errors in red color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resolved after another install. Probably something to do with installation options.